# Using React Leaflet Draw in project - EditControl issues

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to use React-Leaflet-Draw to add polygons to a mapping project I'm working on. Coming unstuck on the use of EditControls.

I imported Edit control as per the example

```
import { EditControl } from '../src';
```

With an index.js file in src folder with:

```
export EditControl from './EditControl';
```

I added some code to do some different things to the example but it still ran fine (in the example version).

When I tried to run this on another project, using the same code I get the error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected {
```

From the index.js file, using the same export command. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any thoughts on why it might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: did you have any luck on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 'leaflet-draw'

```
npm install 'leaflet-draw'
```